# Backup / Restore mailbox using IMAP

Tags: windows, email, thunderbird, imap

Kindly point out an application to automate the process of backing up and restore my IMAP email account?

I use ThunderBird 3.1 currently as my client but its very manual to drag and drop my inbox, any other application or addons to automatically do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "backup and restore my IMAP email account"? The whole point of IMAP is that its server based so what's the problem that requires you to fiddle at the client end?

Comment: well I want to make a local backup and restore the data ta another account

Comment: Ah, that would be a copy then rather than a restore... that does kind of make sense (having done something similar too long ago to remember exactly how)

Comment: http://www.broobles.com/imapsize/ is a possibility, but I haven't tested it, just read about it but then didn't need it myself.  It brags of a mbox2eml utility for exporting your mail to .eml files (which can be imported by many other mail clients).  Let us know if this works for you.

Comment: @Robert Kerr: do you know of any windows based applications to do the same, at the moment I'm doing the transfers manually by ThunderBird